# Error in 2 * Y[j] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

I have run the following program and I got this error "Error in 2 * Y[j] : non-numeric argument to binary operator"
I am extracting runoff events from stormflow data.

```
#' Smooth runoff response data
#'
#' Smooths runoff response data for runoff event delineation using a moving average filter (window is 3).
#' @param X The response data vector.
#' @param Pass The number of filter passes used on \code{X}.
#' @return A smoothed response vector.
#' @examples 
#' smoothed_response <- smooth.curve(response, 3)
#' @note This is an R implementation of a function from the MATLAB toolbox HydRun.
#' @references Tang, W., & Carey, S. K. (2017). HydRun: a MATLAB toolbox for rainfall runoff analysis. Hydrological Processes, 31(15), 2670-2682.
#' @export

smooth.curve <- function(X, Pass) {
  
  Y <- X
  
  if (Pass > 0) {
    
    for (i in 1:Pass) {
      for (j in 2:(length(X)-1)) {
        Y[j] <- (Y[j-1] + 2*Y[j] + Y[j+1])/4
      }
    }
  }
  
  return(Y)
  
}
```

Comment: Please include an example in which you are running into that error.

Comment: I am running it in R Studio

Comment: smooth.curve <- function(X, Pass) {
  
  Y <- X
  
  if (Pass > 0) {
    
    for (i in 1:Pass) {
      for (j in 2:(length(X)-1)) {
        Y[j] <- (Y[j-1] + 2*Y[j] + Y[j+1])/4
      }
    }
  }
  
  return(Y)
  
}

Comment: Error in 2 * Y[j] : non-numeric argument to binary operator